# How to Maximize the window,without clicking the maximize Avaialble in the title bar

Tags: windows

When opening the window , it should open in the maximize mode.I do not want to click on maximize in the title bar,How to achive this?
Should i sendMessage to the window at the point of window opening in the code?
Please helpp
In Visual studio,c++ language

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 function with `SW_MAXIMIZE` as the second parameter.